# How to scan variables into a data structure from inside a function in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, loops, data-structures

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_TITLE_SIZE 20
#define MAX_BOOKS 10

struct Book{
  int _isbn;
  float _price;
  int _year;
  char _title[MAX_TITLE_SIZE];
  int _qty;
};

void displayInventory(const struct Book book[], const int size){

  int i;

  printf("===================================================\n");
  printf("ISBN      Title              Year Price  Quantity\n");
  printf("---------+------------------+----+-------+--------\n");

  //iterate through objects
  if(size == 0){
    printf("The inventory is empty!\n");
    printf("===================================================");
  }
  else{
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
      printf("%-10.0d%-18s%5d $%-8.2f%-8d\n", book[i]._isbn, book[i]._title, book[i]._year, book[i]._price, book[i]._qty);
    }
  }
}

void addBook(struct Book book[], int *size){

  if(*size == MAX_BOOKS){
    printf("the inventory is full\n");
  }
  else{

     //increment inventory size
    (*size)++;  //*size will move the pointer to the next in position/hashcode
    //++*size also works



    printf("ISBN:");
    scanf("%d", book[*size]._isbn);
    printf("Title:");
    scanf("%s", book[*size]._title);
    printf("Year:");
    scanf("%d", book[*size]._year);
    printf("Price:");
    scanf("%f", book[*size]._price);
    printf("Quantity:");
    scanf("%d", book[*size]._qty);

    printf("The book is sucessfully added to the inventory.\n");
    printf("\n");
  }
}

int main(void){

  int size = 0;
  struct Book book[MAX_BOOKS];

  book[0]._isbn = 1234;
  printf("Create string: ");
  scanf("%s", book[0]._title);
  book[0]._year = 1992;
  book[0]._price = 192.90;
  book[0]._qty = 2;

  size++;

  addBook(book, &size);

  displayInventory(book, size);
  return 0;
}
```

So I have this bookkeeping system that I'm trying to make and what I want to do is add a new book to the book[] array structure.

When I try and input the ISBN for a book in my addBook() function the whole application ends with non-zero status.

How do I write into a data structure from a function? I'm sorry if it's a stupid question but I've been stuck on this for a while.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's a link to the repl.it: https://repl.it/JRPH/4

Comment: `scanf("%d", book[*size]._isbn);` --> `scanf("%d", &book[*size]._isbn);`

Comment: `(*size)++;` move to last of else-block.

Comment: The title can not contain spaces.

Comment: Since ISBN has 13 digits, it can not be held with 32 bit int.

Answer (score 1):

You should refer to `address` of variable when using `scanf`. Specifically, `scanf("%d", book[*size]._isbn);` -> `scanf("%d", &(book[*size]._isbn));` and so on...

Take a look at [this](https://repl.it/JRPH/5).